# How to store a downloaded file object from S3 to a local directory

Tags: java, file, amazon-s3, download

I'm trying to download a file from S3 using AWS SDK for Java and store the particular file in a  local directory in my PC.

The code I wrote for downloading the object is:

```
public void download(String key) {
S3Object obj=s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketname,key));
}
```

But what I actually want to do is to pass the local path as a parameter instead of key and store the downloaded file obj in that particular directory say /tmp/AWSStorage/ in my linux box.

Can you please suggest a way of doing it?

Comment: I haven't used this API, but from the docs it seems like `obj.getDataInputStream()` will return the stream which you could copy to your file with i.e. `IOUtils.copy(is, new FileOutputStream(file));`.

Comment: One thing to note, don't directly cast `S3ObjectInputStream` to `InputStream` if passing the object around, make sure you use `S3ObjectInputStream`'s `getDelegateStream()` method.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In the line `S3Object obj=s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketname,key));`
bucketname is the S3BucketName and Key is the object name, it is not a local file path.
Key - is the combination of common-prefix / objectname

i.e. if you file is saved at root of bucket then only name of the object will be the key i.e. myfile.txt
but if your file is save like myfolder1/myfolder2/myfile.txt then 
myfolder1/myfolder is your common-prefix and myfile.txt is objectname.

```
S3Object obj=s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketname,"myfolder1/myfolder2/myfile.txt"));
```

Comment: The question here is where to specify local path, not the path on S3

Answer (score 9):

I used:

```
s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket,key),file);
```

It worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

There is an [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#getObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest-java.io.File-) to directly download file to local path

```
ObjectMetadata getObject(GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest,
                     File destinationFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java >=1.6, you can directly copy the files downloaded to local directory without any problem of file corruption. Check the code:

```
S3Object fetchFile = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName));
final BufferedInputStream i = new BufferedInputStream(fetchFile.getObjectContent());
InputStream objectData = fetchFile.getObjectContent();
Files.copy(objectData, new File("D:\\" + fileName).toPath()); //location to local path
objectData.close();
```

With Java 1.6 and above, you can directly specify path in Files.copy function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `obj.getDataInputStream()` to get the file. And then `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` `copy` method to copy.

```
S3Object obj=s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketname,key));
File file=new File("/tmp/AWSStorage/"+key);

// if the directory does not exist, create it
if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
```

And then you can use either of following.

```
try {
    IOUtils.copy(obj.getDataInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(file));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OR**

```
BufferedReader reader=null;
BufferedWriter out=null;
String data = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileObj.getDataInputStream()));
    out = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(file));
    while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.write(data);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    reader.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: I found this API for s3Client:   s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName,key),file) which gets the object metadata and stores it in the file in the local location. Are there similar methods in s3Client to store the complete file in the location???

Comment: Does this method store only the object metadata it returns in the file or the object contents? Its really confusing...Help please